# The gdb is shows 0xc0000142 error, it is not running too, please help me out

Tags: debugging, gdb, tui

I have recently installed gdb from Mysys2. However it isn't functioning properly. When I try to use gdb for debugging I am having this error as seen in the pic. I am not able to debug, and inputting is also not possible. Please help me out rectifying this problem.
[image: cmd prompt of the issue]

Comment: This will probably help: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/1744#issuecomment-256146266.

Comment: One of the fundamental problem in my case is that I am unable to do any form of inputting operations